# How to change figcaption by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a figure, which contain the image. Source of image can change. So I need to change the figcaption and make it equal the title of image. Is there any way how to do it?

```
<figure><img id="largeImg" src="https://js.cx/gallery/img1-lg.jpg" align="middle">
  <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
```

Comment: _"and make it equal the title of image"_... What title?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
$('figcaption').text($('#largeImg').attr('title'))
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/u46yga7k/)

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, interesting how we always have strange answers to unclear questions ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I dont think it is strange answer because SO clearly mentioned _title of image_ . He may have missed adding the title attribute  but that does not stop from answering. Also the bigger picture is to show how to update the figcaption text by using *text* method and *attr* method. Hope it clarifies your concern